# MS Access 2007 DAO open recordset using a specified index

Tags: ms-access, indexing, recordset

This is the first time I've asked a question although I have found the solutiion to many of my broblems here over the years.

I have a frustrating problem to which I cannot find an answer. I want to do the initial read prior to a read sequentially through a linked table opened as a dynaset DAO recordset using a specific index name as defined on the table.

My code returns error 3251 'operation is not supported...' on the .index line. No doubt there is an obvious solution (Mind you, I'm trying to avoid opening a SQL query which would be the obvious answer).

```
Public Function IOrdCustomerStock(CustomerID As Long, ProductID As Long, KeepRsOpen As Boolean, Optional UseIndexName As String) As Boolean

    Set zcls_CS.CS_rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Name:=CS_TableName, Type:=RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset)
    With zcls_CS.CS_rs
        If Not IsMissing(UseIndexName) Then
            .Index = UseIndexName
        End If
        .FindFirst "CS_CustomerID = " & CustomerID & " and CS_ProductID = " & ProductID
        If .NoMatch Then
            zcls_CS.CS_EOF = True
        Else
            zcls_CS.CS_EOF = False
            zcls_CS.CS_ID = .Fields("[ID]")
            zcls_CS.CS_CustomerID = .Fields("[CS_CustomerID]")
            zcls_CS.CS_PhysSalesStock = .Fields("[CS_PhysSalesStock]")
            zcls_CS.CS_ProductID = .Fields("[CS_ProductID]")
            zcls_CS.CS_PurQuantityRecvd = .Fields("[CS_PurQuantityRecvd]")
            zcls_CS.CS_PurUnitDesc = .Fields("[CS_PurUnitDesc]")
            zcls_CS.CS_PurUnitFactor = .Fields("[CS_PurUnitFactor]")
            zcls_CS.CS_SaleQuantityAlloc = .Fields("[CS_SaleQuantityAlloc]")
            zcls_CS.CS_SaleQuantityOrdered = .Fields("[CS_SaleQuantityOrdered]")
            zcls_CS.CS_SaleUnitDesc = .Fields("[CS_SaleUnitDesc]")
            zcls_CS.CS_SaleUnitFactor = .Fields("[CS_SaleUnitFactor]")
        End If
    End With
    If Not KeepRsOpen Then
        Call IOclCustomerStock
    End If

    IOrdCustomerStock = Not zcls_CS.CS_EOF

End Function
```

Comment: P.S. If I change the recordset type to Type:=RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenTable then I get an invalid operation on the openrecordset line and also if I change the recordert definition from dao.recordset to plain recordset.

Comment: P.P.S. I get the same errors if I use a locally defined recordset (just to eliminate any probems using a recordset defined as an element of a class). I think the basic problem is that I need to open the recordset as a table type to enable me to use the index property of the recordset but I'm obviously doing something (I expect pretty obvious) wrong.

Comment: Apologies for the typo's ... I'm struggling with a French keyboard on my backup computer as my main machine is pooly...

Comment: The issue is due to my opening a linked table _ it works fine for a locally defined table (except the need to use 'Seek' instead of 'FindFirst'). Do any of you clever people out there have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I'd restricted the problem to linked tables, I found the following post:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d402a8d2-0771-458c-b57e-09e2d6f0c536/trying-to-open-a-linked-table-whats-going-on?forum=accessdev

I don't pretend to understand the OpenDatabase parameters but it works. I just need to add the usual error handling to my little proof of concept:

```
Public Function IOksInitRsIX1CustomerStock(UseIndexName As String, CustomerID As Long, ProductID As Long) As Boolean
Set zcls_CS.CS_rs = OpenDatabase(Mid(DBEngine(0)(0).TableDefs(CS_TableName).Connect, 11)).OpenRecordset(CS_TableName)
With zcls_CS.CS_rs
    zcls_CS.CS_rs.Index = UseIndexName
    If (CustomerID > 0 And ProductID > 0) Then
        .Seek "=", CustomerID, ProductID
    Else
        If CustomerID > 0 Then
            .Seek "=", CustomerID
        End If
    End If
    If .NoMatch Then
        zcls_CS.CS_EOF = True
    Else
        zcls_CS.CS_EOF = False
        zcls_CS.CS_ID = .Fields("[ID]")
        zcls_CS.CS_CustomerID = .Fields("[CS_CustomerID]")
        zcls_CS.CS_PhysSalesStock = .Fields("[CS_PhysSalesStock]")
        zcls_CS.CS_ProductID = .Fields("[CS_ProductID]")
        zcls_CS.CS_PurQuantityRecvd = .Fields("[CS_PurQuantityRecvd]")
        zcls_CS.CS_PurUnitDesc = .Fields("[CS_PurUnitDesc]")
        zcls_CS.CS_PurUnitFactor = .Fields("[CS_PurUnitFactor]")
        zcls_CS.CS_SaleQuantityAlloc = .Fields("[CS_SaleQuantityAlloc]")
        zcls_CS.CS_SaleQuantityOrdered = .Fields("[CS_SaleQuantityOrdered]")
        zcls_CS.CS_SaleUnitDesc = .Fields("[CS_SaleUnitDesc]")
        zcls_CS.CS_SaleUnitFactor = .Fields("[CS_SaleUnitFactor]")
    End If
End With

IOksInitRsIX1CustomerStock = Not zcls_CS.CS_EOF
```

End Function